# What is the meaning of progress in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

#### Description

For simple scan or group by queries, the meaning of `progress`(show in JSON FORMAT as statistics) is quite straight forward, the I/O amount of leaf nodes. But for complex queries like distributed global join, a temporary memory table will be created, and the `progress` information will also count those read from memory. The data read from the temporary table will **overlap** with the data read from disk. I want to understand what is the design intention for progress, is this overlap a legitimate behavior for `progress`?

#### Example

settings: two nodes

local tables(execute on both nodes):

```
CREATE TABLE test.t1_48021_local
(
    `a` UInt64,
    `b` UInt64
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY a
ORDER BY a
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
CREATE TABLE test.t2_48021_local
(
    `a` UInt64,
    `c` UInt64
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY a
ORDER BY a
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

distributed table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.t1_48021
(
    `a` UInt64,
    `b` UInt64
)
ENGINE = Distributed('ch_benchmark', 'test', 't1_48021_local', a);
CREATE TABLE test.t2_48021
(
    `a` UInt64,
    `c` UInt64
)
ENGINE = Distributed('ch_benchmark', 'test', 't2_48021_local', a);
```

data(execute on both nodes):

```
INSERT INTO test.t1_48021_local (a, b) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO test.t2_48021_local (a, c) VALUES (1, 1);
```

query:

```
select * from t2_48021 GLOBAL JOIN t1_48021 ON t1_48021.a=t2_48021.a FORMAT JSON;
```

result:

```
{
        "meta":
        [
                {
                        "name": "a",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "c",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "t1_48021.a",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "b",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                }
        ],

        "data":
        [
                {
                        "a": 1,
                        "c": 1,
                        "t1_48021.a": 1,
                        "b": 1
                },
                {
                        "a": 1,
                        "c": 1,
                        "t1_48021.a": 1,
                        "b": 1
                }
,
                {
                        "a": 1,
                        "c": 1,
                        "t1_48021.a": 1,
                        "b": 1
                },
                {
                        "a": 1,
                        "c": 1,
                        "t1_48021.a": 1,
                        "b": 1
                }

        ],

        "rows": 4,

        "statistics":
        {
                "elapsed": 0.002541948,
                "rows_read": 6,
                "bytes_read": 96,
                "total_cpu_seconds": 0.001452,
                "io_wait_seconds": 0
        }
}
```

Both distributed tables only contain 2 rows, adds up to 4. So in my view, the statistics should return `rows_read` as 4, but the result is 6.

Comment: hey man, why don't you use fiddle and provide an example? https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/ I tried running your code and I have different JSON at the end

Comment: @techkuz I opened your website, but I found it doesnt have a setting for two node.

Comment: it is not mine actually, but of the creators of clickhouse. There is a "test_cluster_two_shards" cluster

Comment: @techkuz I tried your suggestion. I guess its because my local setting is wrong somewhere, so it is actually one shard in my local setting. But I assume this is not related to my question. my question is "does clickhouse progress simply adds up whatever rows read from non-remote leaf nodes?" And is this behavior intended by design, or simply because no one really cares about the progress?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have only one Clickhouse node?

1. GLOBAL JOIN creates a temporary table using `(select * from t1_48021)` = 2
2. GLOBAL JOIN propagates the temporary table to all shards
3. The shard1 reads the temporary table = 2
4. The shard1 reads the `t1_48021` = 2

`2+2+2 = 6`

Comment: I do have two clickhouse node, but maybe I haven't got the settings correct.
And in your step 3, actually a table in memory is being read, I think this should be different from disk table, but in the end, the progress simply adds them together. Is this a legitimate behavior? Does progress simply means rows and bytes read from table regardless of the table's type?